# yum on Centos stuck at "loaded plugins: fastestmirror"

Tags: centos, yum

When trying to install a package using yum on Centos, the command is getting stuck at the first part:

```
loaded plugins: fastestmirror
```

I've tried:

1. removing /var/cache/yum/timedhosts.txt [See suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/384963/yum-hangs-and-wont-respond)
2. yum update yum
3. making sure there are no other processes running and removing /var/run/yum.pid
4. yum clean all [See suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/271248/yum-stucks-on-update-centos-5-6)
5. Checked that DNS works for all the servers in the /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo files
6. Set the enabled flag in vi /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf // enabled=0 [See Suggestion](http://www.adminspoint.com/server-administration/355-yum-disable-fastestmirror-plugin-centos.html)

... still having the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me what ended up fixing it was this:

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__*
rpm --rebuilddb -v -v
```

Then rerunning yum command I was trying to run in the first place.

It got stuck for about a minute on:

```
Determining fastest mirrors
```

...but then it completed without errors

[Suggested Here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1049988)

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions you listed and it still hangs.  Made progress by following the steps provided here: http://superuser.com/questions/384963/yum-hangs-and-wont-respond

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question and answers appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 13):

Worked for me : ([+](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1049988))

Edit the following file.

```
/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf
```

Change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` to disable the fastestmorror plugin.

That should fix it.

You don't need to restart anything for that change to take effect. Just run yum again.

Answer (score 1):

If you use only ipv4 address but ipv6 address is active. Disable the ipv6 address and then try again.

```
#vi /etc/sysctl.conf 

net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1

#sysctl -p
```